# echo file path into Javascript breaks image zoom viewer

Tags: javascript, php

I had a working image viewer with zoom that I got from here:
http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

This code is for my product view page and needs to pull in multiple pictures from mysql. I tried echoing out the file path with php into the html that is being targeted by javascript on the "zoom_01" ID and also in the javascript itself (as is necessary for the picture viewer)

I get an image to display but then the zoom functionality is gone. 
Shouldn't it be all the same to javascript if the values are hard coded or echoed in? If you can think of anything to try I would really appreciate it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<div="display"><img id="zoom_01" src='<?php echo $onesmall ?>' 
data-zoom-image="<?php echo $onelarge ?>"/> </div>

$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 1000,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 1500,
}); 

$( "#gal_1" ).on( "click", function() {
document.getElementById("zoom_01").src=<?php echo $onesmall?>;
$("#zoom_01").data('zoom-image',<?php echo $onelarge?>);
$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 1000,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 1500
});
});
```

Comment: please show the part of your code where you set `$onesmall` and `$onelarge` (The SQL query and all other changes to your variables)

Answer (score 0):

you are correct in saying it's the same to JavaScript, since it's executed after the entire server side code has finished executing - but you missed a little yet key thing:

```
document.getElementById("zoom_01").src=<?php echo $onesmall?>; // syntax error!
$("#zoom_01").data('zoom-image',<?php echo $onelarge?>); // syntax error!
```

will create something like this:

```
document.getElementById("zoom_01").src=my-small-img.jpg; // syntax error!
$("#zoom_01").data('zoom-image',my-image-path.jpg); // syntax error!
```

**without quotes!**

update it to:

```
document.getElementById("zoom_01").src='<?php echo $onesmall?>';
$("#zoom_01").data('zoom-image','<?php echo $onelarge?>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I couldn't use the quotes because of the highlighting on my text editor but that did the trick. Awesome thank you.

Comment: no problem, did the same mistake enough times to look for it :) feel free to mark as accepted